# Regular expression. The regex fails when prohibited characters are on second line

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have the follow regex.

```
^(?!.*&#.*)[\u00e1\u00c1\u00e9\u00c9\u00ed\u00cd\u00f3\u00d3\u00fa\u00da\u00f1\u00d1\u00fc\u00dc\u00ab\u00bb\u00bf\u00a1`\w\d\s\-'.,&amp;@:;®?!()$#/‘’*“”&quot;]+$
```

The issue is when the text below is entered on second line the regex does not catch the "&#" as not allowed character.
Regex does not find a match with input in on one line.
The combination of &# is not allowed.
However if the input is like below i.e &# is on second ine
The combination of
 &# is not allowed.

It will allow. although the prohibited characters "&#" are still in the input.
Not sure what tweak is need for regex to work if these character are on secode line.

Comment: The anchors `^` and `$` will match the ends of a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, replace `(?!.*&#.*)` by `(?![\s\S]*&#[\s\S]*)`

The dot `.` match any character except the new lines. That is your error.

That match all the space characters `\s` and that all the none-space characters `\S`. That mean that if you use the following character class `[\s\S]`, you can match every single character.

Good success

Comment: Ok then, accept the answer to indicate that the question no longer require help. Have a good day.